# 'awk' version of this Python code?

Tags: python, awk

This is my Python code:

```
with open('a') as f:
    a, b = f
    a, b = a.strip(), b.strip()
```

While this is my AWK code:

```
awk '{printf $1":"}' a
```

I would like to modify my AWK code so that it can do exactly what the Python code above does.

As seen above, the AWK code is a mess.

I need it to grab line 1 and 2 from the file `a` and permit me to
use those variables. Like it is possible in the Python code.

Or perhaps there is something else that is native to Linux?

That I should look into of?

If I am not mistaken, there is:

- [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)
- [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)
- [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)

But the fastest of all would be AWK.

Comment: in your python codes, what does `a, b = f` do?

Comment: @Kent: If there are exactly two lines in the file, `a` and `b` get those two lines; if there are more or fewer, it raises an exception. (From the description below, it sounds like he doesn't care about the exception for longer or shorter files, he just needs it to work the same way for 2-line files.)

Comment: so you mean your file `a` has only two lines?

Comment: What makes you think awk would be "fastest of all"? And why is that important? The I/O time to read one disk block will probably vastly overwhelm the processing cost in any language, which is probably on the order of 1 microsecond.

Comment: @Kent, yes only two lines.

Comment: Also… your Python code doesn't actually do _anything_ but spin up the drive and waste a tiny bit of CPU; it doesn't even print anything.

Comment: @abarnert see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193867/how-do-you-deal-with-legitimate-questions-from-a-troll for some context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope your Python code has good error/exception handling, in case file `a` has more than two lines.

I assume that your file has exactly two lines, and then you could do it in AWK:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{ #here you could do whatever with a[1] (a) and a[2] (b)}' file
```

For example:

```
kent$  seq 2|awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{print "hello "a[1]; print "hi "a[2]}'
hello 1
hi 2
```

Or this:

```
kent$  seq 2|awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{printf "%s:%s\n",a[1],a[2]}'           
1:2
```

I hope this helps.